# Automating appIcon with different Bundle Identifiers

Tags: ios, icons

How can I automate the appIcon with different Bundle Identifiers? I want to make my beta version app uses different appIcons.

I had tried this but it doesn't work.

[image: Icon files named by Bundle Identifiers]

[image: info.plist]

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new target with a different version number and set the icons for each target.